# Is saying that "Heat always flow from hotter to colder object in a isolated system" equivalent to the second principle?

Tags: thermodynamics

In other words, can we make exactly the same predictions as the second principle (that involves entropy) by this phrase without ever introducing entropy ?

Comment: What is your definition of closed system? Maybe your question is more interesting if you meant an isolated system.

Comment: Even an isolated system can have internal power sources that can pump heat the other way around, for a while... so, no, this won't work.

Comment: Clausius version " Heat can never pass from a colder to a warmer body without some other change, connected therewith, occurring at the same time"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics

Answer (score 2):

The Clausius' statement of the second law of thermodynamics states that the **only effect** of a cyclic process **cannot** be the transfer of heat from a cold body to a hot body. That is, for heat to be transferred from a cold to a hot body, work has to be expended, such as in a refrigerator, where the energy to remove heat from inside to the outside is derived from the mains supply. So while it is true that heat flows **spontaneously** from a hot body to a cold body, it is **not generally true** that heat **always** flows from a hotter object to a colder object.